# Execute a parameterized query with BigQuery using apache beam

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam

In my dataflow batch job, I am reading from Bigquery like below

```
PCollection<MyData> myDataPcol=pipeline.apply("Read from BQ",BigQueryIO.read(new MyDataSerializableFunction()).fromQuery(queryString)
```

queryString contains certain values especially in WHERE clause which I need to replace with command line options.

For ex,

```
WHERE date>'2023-05-01'
```

Here the date, I will get from command line options.

Is there anyway to have these as parameters to the BQ query (like parameterized queries) and execute it via BigQueryIO.read

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you wanted the date in your sample to be parameterized? Can you try this sample from the official documentation:

```
    PCollection<MyData> rows =
        pipeline
            .apply(
                "Read from BigQuery query",
                BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
                    .fromQuery(String.format("SELECT * FROM `%s.%s.%s`", project, dataset, table)) //parameterized the from clause part of the select query
                    .usingStandardSql())
            .apply(
                "TableRows to MyData",
                MapElements.into(TypeDescriptor.of(MyData.class)).via(MyData::fromTableRow));
```

Visit [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/) for better visibility of the code sample.

Comment: As of now I do it in this way. This is a kind of string formatting. Isn't it? I would like to have something like this https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#java